# Quickbook Menu is not showing using QBFC SDK

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

I used below code to add menu it's working in one machine but not working on another machine

```
ISubscriptionMsgSetRequest _menuSet = GetSubscribeMsgRequest();
IUIExtensionSubscriptionAdd query =  _menuSet.AppendUIExtensionSubscriptionAddRq();
query.SubscriberID.SetValue(SUBSCRIBER_ID.ToString("B"));
query.COMCallbackInfo.AppName.SetValue(AppName);
```

I am not getting any issue, actually i am not clear with the code

i have taken code from this [url](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0050_documentation/sample_code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check all steps one by one

1. Run your code using administrator account
2. When you will run you code check whether response status is 0? - if it is 0 then continue else check status message and update in your question
3. check whether below code is present
    **InformManager.SubscribeToQBUIExtensionEvents(handleMenuEvents);**
   **ATTACHED EVENT OF MENU CLICK**
4. After successful execution open Quickbook as administrator
5. Then you will get Authorisation box - Allow your plugin to add menu in quickbook, it is required.
6. If you dont get any Autorisation box then go in Edit menu in Quickbook
   Edit->Preference->IntegratedApplication->Company Reference
       Remove your app if it is present, and close & open QB again you will get Autorisation Box
7. Close you Quickbook
8. Open Quickbook as normal user then check your menus and their events
9. If events are not present again you need to check you event attached code.
   10.Happy Quickbook coding

If you have any concern regarding Quickbook feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks @Sai Sherlekar, Point 6 is fabulous for me